# How can I set up the lyxserver

Tags: lyx

I'm attempting to use the LyZ plugin for Zotero and LyX and it requires the LyX server to be present.

I've looked on the [LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXServer) for information and it makes reference to .lyxpipe.in and .lyxpipe.out but these are not present when I install LyX from the Ubuntu repository.

What are these files and how can they be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The English version of the [LyZ](http://www.klubko.net/wp/?page_id=945&lang=en) page has some instructions for this, which I assume are the requirements.   Here's how to set the path you need :

Go to Tools > Preferences > Paths
In the **LyXServer pipe** field, enter `~/.lyx/lyxpipe` and save.

Here's the preferences screen.   You'll want to edit the field highlighted in orange.

[image]

After this, restart LyX.

EDIT: Just to state what may not be the obvious - make sure that this path is the same as in the Zotero pane, Lyx dropbown box > Settings... > Lyx Server.

Comment: Thanks! I think the problem I was having was that I thought the LyXServer pipe had to point to a specific file or folder. I didn't know that you could point it to any folder