# lyxpipe missing in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lyx

I decided to write my thesis in LyX, got everything working nearly perfectly, but I found a strange problem which google cant help with... I tried to import citation from jabref to lyx, got only error "verify that lyx is running and the lyxpipe is valid" lyx running is, but when i tried to solve lyxpipe problem, I found out that I dont have lyxpipe (lyx and jabref were installed via ubuntu software center and after some searching, I found out that lyxpipe should be there, I tried to remove and reinstall lyx via software center, but still nothing), dont anyone knows whats wrong with my lyx?

Comment: Same or similar? http://askubuntu.com/questions/26984

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I put path to the home/bla/.lyx 
everything worked